# DS-160 Expiration Date

Tags: visas

[image]

I have recently started to fill in the DS-160 for my visa application. However, while doing so, I can see an expiration date of 10.31.2022, means the form has
already been expired. Nonetheless, I have opened a new form and the date was the same as before. Can anyone share some insights on why it is happening?

Comment: We cannot see what you see. Please use the "Edit" button below your question, followed by the "Moon and Mountains" button above the text-entry box, to add a screen shot of what you're seeing. Before attaching the screen shot, obscure any personal or identifying information.

Answer (score 5):

This is the "OMB number" expiration. OMB is an American governmental agency that evaluates government forms' suitability per the [Paperwork Reduction Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperwork_Reduction_Act). The OMB number is stamped on each form the government creates, and is valid for 3 years.

For DS-160, it apparently expired on October 31st, 2022. That means that the State Department needs to submit the current (or new) form for the OMB re-evaluation. They have done so, but [the OMB hasn't processed the new form yet](https://omb.report/icr/202208-1405-006).

You can use the current form.